# Use repository name in travis CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am facing an issue on Travis CI. I seem not to be able to use the repository name as an environment variable.

I have a Travis build that is setup to build, tag and push a Docker image.

In the after_success section of the .travis.yml file the following command is running

```
docker build -t ${PROJECT}:${TRAVIS_BRANCH} .
```

*(The environment variable ${PROJECT} is the actual name of the repository and is set in the repository settings.)*

The problem is that Docker is using "[secure]" as image name instead of the repository name. I end up with something like

```
Successfully tagged [secure]:staging
```

After that when I am tagging the image the following error is returned

```
Error parsing reference: "/[secure]:staging" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

I have tried to update ${PROJECT} to a random string and it worked fine.

Is there a way to use the repository name as a environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your `$PROJECT` contains a leading slash which might be the problem.